# display firebase images array in custom view (icarousel)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, icarousel

The users of my app have the ability to make a post and when they make a post they can upload more than one picture. The issue I have is viewing the pictures in my app. This is how the node looks in firebase:

```
  },    
  "-Kjy7sfa7pWmlawqWTsN" : {    
    "image" : "CfHWd.jpg",  
    "imageFive" : "30fQI.jpg",  
    "imageFour" : "uOnVB.jpg",  
    "imageThree" : "eHMOY.jpg", 
    "imageTwo" : "jQCLu.jpg",   
  }
```

This is how I retrieve them from firebase:

```
if let stringImage = self.imageNames {

            let imageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage)")

            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    self.ImageOne = UIImage(data: data!)!



                }else {
                    print("Error downloading image:" )
                }

                if let stringImages = self.imagesTwo {

                    let imageRefs = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImages)")

                    imageRefs.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageTwo = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
                if let stringImage3 = self.imagesThree {

                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage3)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageThree = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
                if let stringImage4 = self.imagesFour {

                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage4)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageFour = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
                if let stringImage5 = self.imagesFive {
                    AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()
                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage5)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                            self.ImageFive = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}



            })}
```

Now my issue is displaying them in a special view called icarousel. I was successfully able to display images from my assets folder in icarousel doing this:

```
  var imageArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    @IBOutlet weak var carouselView: iCarousel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.carouselView.delegate = self
        self.carouselView.dataSource = self

imageArray = ["imageOne", "imageTwo", "imageThree"]
carouselView.type = .wheel
        carouselView.reloadData()
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!

        if view == nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 130))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        }else{
            imageView = view as! UIImageView

        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(imageArray.object(at: index))")
        return imageView

        }


    public func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }
```

However, I attempted to retrieve all the images from firebase and place them into an array:

```
imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive]
```

but it doesn't work, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong
This is my attempt to set up icarousel from firebase:

```
var imageArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
@IBOutlet var carouselView: iCarousel!

var ImageOne = UIImage()
var ImageTwo = UIImage()
var ImageThree = UIImage()
var ImageFour = UIImage()
var ImageFive = UIImage()

    var images: NSArray! = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
self.carouselView.delegate = self
        self.carouselView.dataSource = self
 if let stringImage = self.imageNames {

            let imageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage)")

            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    self.ImageOne = UIImage(data: data!)!



                }else {
                    print("Error downloading image:" )
                }

                if let stringImages = self.imagesTwo {

                    let imageRefs = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImages)")

                    imageRefs.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageTwo = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
                if let stringImage3 = self.imagesThree {

                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage3)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageThree = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
                if let stringImage4 = self.imagesFour {

                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage4)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageFour = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}
                if let stringImage5 = self.imagesFive {
                    AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()
                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage5)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                            self.ImageFive = UIImage(data: data!)!


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }



                    })}



            })}


       imageArray = [self.ImageOne, self.ImageTwo, self.ImageThree, self.ImageFour, self.ImageFive]


        carouselView.type = .rotary
        carouselView.reloadData()


    }
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var imageView: UIImageView!

        if view == nil {
            imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 230, height: 270))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            carousel.clipsToBounds = true
        }else{
            imageView = view as! UIImageView

        }


        imageView.image = imageArray[index] as? UIImage;
        print(imageArray)
        return imageView

    }



    public func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }
```

Comment: In `carousel`, set the image to `imageView.image = imageArray[index]`

Comment: `if let stringImage = self.imageNames{}` where is it called? Since there should be async/background process, is you array full when you call `carouselView.reloadData()`?

Comment: In imageArray you are not saving image names.. but you are saving images.. either save image names and save them locally for better performance.. or go with @Wei Jay's solution..

Comment: @WeiJay I did that but it still doesn't work

Comment: Also, downloading image is an asynchronous function, remember to call `carouselView.reloadData()` when the image is ready

Comment: I also did that, I have updated my question to show exactly what I have done so far @WeiJay thank you

Comment: I mean, put it in `completion`, after each `self.Image# = UIImage(data: data!)!`

Comment: what you get as output of "print(imageArray)"?

Comment: @DimpleShah (
    "<UIImage: 0x1702847e0>, {0, 0}",
    "<UIImage: 0x1702849c0>, {0, 0}",
    "<UIImage: 0x170284a10>, {0, 0}",
    "<UIImage: 0x170284f10>, {0, 0}",
    "<UIImage: 0x170284d30>, {0, 0}"
)

Comment: @WeiJay I just did, still nothing

Comment: keep breakpoint and check whether it goes every time in if or in else.. above the "imageView.image = " line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an imageArray to keep your images from firebase, and reload the carousel when everything is done.

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]() 

if let stringImage = self.imageNames {
    let imageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage)")
    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
        guard let error != nil else { return }

        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            imageArray.append(image)

            if imageArray.count ==  self.imageNames.count { carouselView.reloadData() }
        }
    })
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    if view == nil {
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 230, height: 270))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        carousel.clipsToBounds = true
    }else{
        imageView = view as! UIImageView
    }


    imageView.image = imageArray[index]
    print(imageArray)
    return imageView

}
```

Comment: we are making progress!! Images are now being displayed! however, not all post have five images but when I click on any one post, it shows all the images in my database and not the one specific to the post

Comment: You have to check your click logic. The index should be corresponding to which image you tapped.

Comment: can I use something other than imageArray.append(image) because when I click on the cell and leave and click again it adds the same image twice and if I leave again it add the same image another time

Comment: you can just use `imageArray.removeAll()` when images should be updated

Comment: ok now this seems to be the last problem, do you know why when I click the cell the first time nothing shows but when I click it a second time the image appears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146246/discussion-between-wei-jay-and-juelizabeth).

Comment: I forgot to mention I know the segue is working because I am passing text data and that appears on the first click, just not the image